# Python, getting name of a file at the creation of a object

Tags: python, python-module

i dont know if this wont be a duplicate but i havent found anything, but in that case sorry. 
Now to my question. 
I want to make simple idk how to call it basicly script that would help me write to json file more easy.
What i have rn:

```py
import json

def addValue(pathToFile, index, value):
    with open(pathToFile, "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    data[index] = value

    with open(pathToFile, "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

And my question is how could i make this so that i can create some object at the start and then add the file to it and then just use the object again and again with the same file. Something that i wouldnt have to provide the file name at every call of the function. 
 Something similar to this:

```py
import Tkinter

tk = Tkinter.tk()
```

or:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='test.log')
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

sorry if i wrote this code wring idk really how these modules work

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write open twice as you can just access the file with "r+" which also gives you write access to the file. The seek method sets the writing to the beginning of the file so you can override the old json.

```
import json

def addValue(pathToFile, index, value):
    with open(pathToFile, "r+") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        data[index] = value
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, file, index=4)
```

If this is not ideal, a CSV file may be more suitable as you can continue to add data by just writing to a new line, and it is easier to deal with larger sets of data.